# nginx reverse proxy: how to hide timeout software info?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

nginx is used as reverse proxy. The following info will show if a request takes too long.

How to hide the following nginx info?

```
504 Gateway Time-out
nginx/1.25.1
```

Just say:

```
504 Gateway Time-out
```

Open source info/version can be used by attacker to exploit potential security bugs.